# How can I create a Table as Follows

Tags: flutter

The table is creating perfectly fine, but I want the table structure like [this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/52523326/61457419-e63cce80-a985-11e9-80c7-178722dc2352.png)!

But I am getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCVZ7.png) view.

This is the source code I have come up with:

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
DataTable(
  columns: <DataColumn>[
    DataColumn(
      numeric: true,
      label: Container(
          child: Text(
              "ID", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white)),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          width: 50,
          height: 30,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(), color: Colors.lightBlue)),
      tooltip: "ID OF THE NAME")
  ],
  rows:[
    DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[
      DataCell(
        Row(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: Dismissible(
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(data)),
              key: ObjectKey(value++),
              onDismissed: (direction){
                setState(() {
                  _add.remove(data);
                });
              },
          ))
        ]),
      )
    ])
  ]
);
```